Love with a non Muslim girl at work
I’m currently working at a retail store and this girl started it working more than 3 months ago, since she came, I like her, I have feelings for her, I’m thinking about talking to her and introduce myself to her. Get to know her better. I can’t keep my eye away from her. I am in love with her. Just curious I don’t want to do anything haram. Any advise!

Go introduce yourself, show her the beauty of Islam and see if she accepts.
If she doesn't accepts Islam than you are not allowed to marry her. Then she is just a test for you.
If she accepts Islam then it is a sign that she trusts you and respect you.
Send your parents to her place.
Inshallah you will make a great couple and a good relationship as a student or teacher
